# is it possible to add a list to a structure?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

Is it possible to add a list to a struct?

```
public struct test
{
    public string x;
    list<string> y = new list<string>();
}
```

something like that?

ive been trying but im just not getting it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can have a list in struct but you cannot initialise it with a field initialiser and instead you must use the constructor.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public List<string> MyList;
    public int MyInt;

    public MyStruct(int myInt)
    {
        MyInt = myInt;
        MyList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that you can not have a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: The point is... an struct should NOT reference mutable types (or collections of mutable entities)

Answer (score 1):

struct can have a constructor and you can instantiate the list in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in C# but a structure is just a prototype of how your memory would look. You will have to declare a structure variable to be able to do "new list()" and assign it to a list variable.

something like  struct test a;
a.y = new list();

I have never programmed in C# so please convert my C syntax to C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that - declare a constructor for the struct and create a list instance in the struct constructor. You can't use an initializer as you proposed in your code snippet.

Comment: "private List<object> y = new List<object>();" gives me "error CS0573: `test.y': Structs cannot have instance field initializers" Of course it could be done with a class...